# Two Mongoose collections in the same page in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a route with Express that display results from two different MongoDB collections. When a url is called, it displays the right results. There are two collections. The first works well, but not the second (I have a schema for the two of them)

```
router.get('/demo/:cars_getroute', (req, res, next) => {
Democar.findOne({cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute})
    .then((democars) => {
        res.render('demo/fichecar-demo', { marque: democars.marque,
            modele: democars.modele,
            sous_modele: democars.sous_modele,
            sous_modele2: democars.sous_modele2,
            type: democars.type
        });
        Democarauction.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute })
            .then((democarauctions) => {
                res.render('demo/fichecar-demo', { marqueauction: democarauctions.gm_url });
            });
    });
```

})

How can I have the second collection on my page ?

EDIT: My models:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const CarSchema = new Schema({
    objectId: {
        type: Number
    },
    sous_modele2: {
        type: String
    },
    marque: {
        type: String
    },
    modele: {
        type: String
    },
    sous_modele: {
        type: String
    },
    type: {
        type: String
    },
    precision: {
        type: String
    },
    years_interval: {
        type: String
    },
    cars_getroute: {
        type: String
    },
    img_url: {
        type: String
    },
    cote: {
        cote_1989: {
            cote_1989_f: String,
            cote_1989_eu: {
                cote_1989_excp: Number,
                cote_1989_concours: Number,
                cote_1989_base: Number,
                cote_1989_be: Number,
                cote_1989_me: Number,
                cote_1989_ar: Number,
                cote_1989_epa: Number
            }
        },
        cote_2004: {
            cote_2004_excp: Number,
            cote_2004_concours: Number,
            cote_2004_base: Number,
            cote_2004_be: Number,
            cote_2004_me: Number,
            cote_2004_ar: Number,
            cote_2004_epa: Number
        },
        cote_2014: {
            cote_2014_excp: Number,
            cote_2014_concours: Number,
            cote_2014_base: Number,
            cote_2014_be: Number,
            cote_2014_me: Number,
            cote_2014_ar: Number,
            cote_2014_epa: Number
        },
        cote_2017: {
            cote_2017_excp: Number,
            cote_2017_concours: Number,
            cote_2017_base: Number,
            cote_2017_be: Number,
            cote_2017_me: Number,
            cote_2017_ar: Number,
            cote_2017_epa: Number
        },
        cote_2019: {
            cote_2019_excp: Number,
            cote_2019_concours: Number,
            cote_2019_base: Number,
            cote_2019_be: Number,
            cote_2019_me: Number,
            cote_2019_ar: Number,
            cote_2019_epa: Number
        },
    },
    cote_actual: Number,
    performance: {
        perfo1989: String,
        perfo2004: String,
        perfo2014: String,
        perfo2017: String
    }   
},
{
    collection: 'carfiche2019'
});

mongoose.model('cars', CarSchema);
```

DemoCarauction:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const DemocarauctionSchema = new Schema({
    objectID: {
        type: Number
    },
    cars_getroute: {
        type: String
    },
    gm_url: {
        type: String
    },
    "results": {
        marque: {
            type: String
        },
        model: {
            type: String
        },
        model_year: {
            type: String
        },
        price_str: {
            type: String
        },
        prince_int: {
            type: Number
        },
        price_currency: {
            type: String
        },
        sold: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        auction_house: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_country: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_date: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_datetime: {
            type: String
        },
        auction_url: {
            type: String
        },
        image_urls: {
            type: String
        },
        price_int_eu: {
            type: Number
        },
    }

},
    {
        collection: 'democarficheauction'
    });

mongoose.model('democarauctions', DemocarauctionSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render twice. I recommend you use `Promise.all`

```
router.get('/demo/:cars_getroute', (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.all([Democar.findOne({cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute}), Democarauction.findOne({ cars_getroute: req.params.cars_getroute })])
    .then(result => {
        const [democars, democarauctions] = result;
        res.render('demo/fichecar-demo', { marque: democars.marque,
            modele: democars.modele,
            sous_modele: democars.sous_modele,
            sous_modele2: democars.sous_modele2,
            type: democars.type,
            marqueauction: democarauctions.gm_url
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle error. 
        console.log(err);
    })

});
```

It is important to add a `catch` block` to handle any error may occur.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It seems right but it doesn't work for me. I want to match databases with the "cars_getroute" key but nothing is display with the Democarauctions database...

Comment: can you post `Democar` and `Democarauction` mongo models?

Comment: if Democarauctions query does not return anything, then the collection may not contain a document with that value, or may contain more than one document that match that value. Try `Democarauction.find` instead of `Democarauction.findOne`. Use `console.log(democarauctions)` after `const [democars, democarauctions] = result;` and check the output

Comment: The output shows that the value is matched but nothing on the frontend...

Comment: Glad to help you.